# Three.js transparency went wrong when changed from r67 to r68

Tags: javascript, three.js, transparency

I experienced a strange issue when changed three.js version from 67 to 68. With version 67 everything looks fine (I can see triangles behind transparent triangles), but it seems it went wrong with version 68.

Here are to fiddles with the same code, but different three.js versions:

`Version 67:` http://jsfiddle.net/gv6stpud/

`Version 68:` http://jsfiddle.net/mkb9m3h5/

Do you have any idea what went wrong?

Comment: MeshLambertMaterial was altered to allow for alpha maps. Maybe this has something to do  with it? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commits/master/src/materials/MeshLambertMaterial.js

Comment: Seems to affect MeshPhongMaterial too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting code for transparent objects changed in r68.

It works again if you invert the order from

```
AddTriangle (scene, material, 0.0);
AddTriangle (scene, material, 0.3);
```

to

```
AddTriangle (scene, material, 0.3);
AddTriangle (scene, material, 0.0);
```